# Adding a Generic allows you to override a method with a different return type?

Tags: java, generics

I ran into this today and the only thing I can think is that this is a bug in the Java compiler.  The following code compiles, but certainly seems incorrect (since testMethod has a differenet signature in the child but overrides the parent) and will throw class cast exceptions at runtime.

```
public interface TestInterface<T> {
  public List<String> testMethod(); // <-- List<String>
}
public class TestClass implements TestInterface {
  @Override
  public List<Integer> testMethod() { // <-- List<Integer> overriding List<String>!!
      return Collections.singletonList(1);
  }
}
```

And using the above structure:

```
public void test() {
  TestInterface<Boolean> test = new TestClass();
  List<String> strings = test.testMethod();
  for (String s : strings) {
    System.out.println(s);
  }
}
```

All of this compiles fine, but will obviously throw class cast exceptions if you run it.

If you remove `<T>` from `TestInterface`, or fill `T` in in the line `TestClass implements TestInterface<T>` then the code will no longer compile, which makes sense. Imo `<T>` should have no bearing on the compilation of `testMethod` since it plays no part in that method.
 Maybe adding `<T>` to TestInterface is causing the compiler to type-erase the method signatures even though `T` doesn't participate in those methods...?

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: +1. Has to be some really, really strange gotcha in the generic implementation

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you instantiate a generic class as a raw type, *all* generic type parameters contained in it are going to be omitted by the compiler, hence it gives you no warnings/errors during compilation. I.e. declaring

```
public class TestClass implements TestInterface ...
```

effectively degrades the code into

```
public interface TestInterface {
  public List testMethod();
}
public class TestClass implements TestInterface {
  @Override
  public List testMethod() {
      return Collections.singletonList(1);
  }
}
```

which indeed compiles fine.

A similar problem was posted a couple of weeks ago, [the answer to which](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436656/java-compiler-bug-with-generics-and-for-each/5436732#5436732) stating that it is not a compiler bug, rather a deliberate design decision for backward compatibility.

Comment: well said, "Erasure" is the key word. Google it and you will see that the bit-code that comes out of the code above has no evidence that Generics was even used.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand it is that generics is a compiler side thing. Nothing about the generic-type information is included in the class file, it's like a compiler hack. Which is why you can easily intermingle generic-laden calls with generic-free classes and there's no problem at runtime.
I hear that all that dotnet stuff makes the generic-type information a first class citizen within the object file.

So anyway, these guys obviously know your problem better than I do, but you should consider than all that's really going on is compiler fluff.