# Java "for" compilation error

Tags: java, for-loop, compilation

i have a problem that stunned me a lot.

I have a class (Bar) with a getter method which returns a List:

```
public abstract class Bar<T extends IdentifiableObject> {
...
public List<Bar> getBars() {
    return bars;
}
...
```

The hierarchy i have is:

```
public abstract class Bar<T extends IdentifiableObject>;
public abstract class IdentifiableObject<T extends Comparable<T>>;
```

Until here everything works fine, the problem is when I execute:

```
for(Bar bar : bars.getBars()) {
}
```

The previous sentence throws a compilation error:

```
incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.util.List<com.x.Bar>
```

I was suprised with this error but i was more suprised when i performed

```
List<Bar> bars = bar.getBars();
Iterator<Bar> iterator = bar.getBars().iterator();
```

both without problems

What is wrong here in the "for" sentence?

Thank you

Comment: Basically this is because you're using the raw type `Bar` instead of a parameterized version. Avoid raw types like the plague.

Comment: You haven't said what `bars` is in your `for` example, but Jon's comment above is almost certainly the issue regardless.

Comment: Java doesn't like mixing raw types with generics.  Try to use one or the other.  If you don't need the generics (as you don't appear to be using `Bar<T>` but rather `Bar`) take the generics out.

Comment: I know i shouldn't use raw types, but in this method i don't need to know the type of Bar. As you see Bar is abstract and will be implemented specifically in another classes. In this method i don't know what kind of Bar i have, so obiously i dont know the T type of Bar, and even more I don't want to know the type because this class does should not access to it's type. The question I have is... why List<Bar> bar = ... works and the "for" not?

Comment: same isssue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5436656/why-does-the-java-compiler-complain-on-using-foreach-with-a-raw-type (with a ref to java specs from Jon)

Answer (score 0):

Create an instance of Bar class as below:

```
Bar<?> bar = new Bar();
```

Add the above line before your code

```
List<Bar> bars = bar.getBars();
Iterator<Bar> iterator = bar.getBars().iterator();
```

Comment: I cannot create an instance of an abstract class

Comment: Sorry.. I missed it.. What does "bars" hold in the below line                 public List<Bar> getBars() { 
    return bars;
}

Comment: It is just for a tree structure with childs of the same type