# How to tell the class of a generic object in Java

Tags: java, generics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to determine the class of a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182636/how-to-determine-the-class-of-a-generic-type)
>   [Get generic type of class at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime)
>   [Java Generics: Accessing Generic Type at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548779/java-generics-accessing-generic-type-at-runtime)

For a generic object parameter to a method

```
void bar(Foo<?> foo) {

}
```

How can you retrieve of the type of the casted object, i.e. the type of **?** ?

Comment: Yeah the type that foo has been casted to. I mean the type of foo is Foo<?>.

Comment: Also worthy: http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208860