# get class object of actual generic type in a static method

Tags: java, generics, types, static

I have a generic static method and I want it to return Class object of the inserted actual generic type.

I have tried it like this:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> Class<T> getClassType() {

    Method thisMethod;
    try {
        thisMethod = CommonTools.class.getMethod("getClass", new Class<?>[0]);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //ErrorLog.error(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        return null;
    }

    Type returnType = thisMethod.getGenericReturnType();
    Type tType = returnType.getClass().getGenericSuperclass();
    ParameterizedType parameterizedType = (ParameterizedType) tType;
    Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) parameterizedType.getActualTypeArguments()[0];

    return clazz;
}
```

My inspiration for this was found in google code morphia library, there they have used something like this:

```
(((Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]))
```

the difference between my code and their code is that they call it for finding generic type in a class - I want it to be used in a method.

My code does not work and it falls within the (Class) conversion line.

Do you have any ideas how to get the current generic type from a static method?

thanks

Comment: why <T> is 2 times it should be public static Class<T> getClassType() if i am not wrong.

Comment: and how should the method than know that T is a generic parameter?

Comment: I think you can create a family of classes by using <T extends YourParentClass>. You could also write a factory instead, give your parent class a type enum and use the factory to convert your classes into specific types based on the enum value passed.

Comment: I want to use it from a static class, your solution is not what I am looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not work. You get method `getClass`, which basically has return type `Class<CommonTools>`, and after that you are calling `getActualTypeArguments`, which will return `Class<CommonTools>`, because TypeArgument is CommonTools.

If you will call `Class<CommonTools> ct = getClassType();` it will work, but then there is no point to have such info.

As far as I know there is no way to get that information because JVM erases all generic info at runtime. 
Simplest solution is that `CommonTools` will get `Class<T>` instance at creation, and will return it, but then it is not so common.

Comment: okay, so it is impossible in java to know the generic type in runtime of a method?

Comment: Yes, read here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html and here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9548779/java-generics-accessing-generic-type-at-runtime