# Java Generics and Raw Types

Tags: java, generics, raw-types

I have the next code:

```java
ArrayList value = new ArrayList<Integer>();  // 1
value.add("Test");  // 2
```

I'm trying to understand line 2. Although I can see that `value.add("Test");` compiles without errors, I can't see the reason it doesn't throw a runtime exception. If `value` is referencing a generic `ArrayList` object, why Java allows to add a `String` to it? Can anyone explain it to me?

The closest explanation I've found about this is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1206028/java-raw-type-and-generics-interaction#answer-1209376), but I still don't understand the core reason:

> ```
> Stack s = new Stack<Integer>()
> ```
>
> This is a legal conversion from a parameterized type to a raw type. You will be able to push value of any type. However, any such operation will result in an "unchecked call" warning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generic types are [erased during](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) [compilation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html). So at runtime, an `ArrayList` is a raw `ArrayList`, no matter if you defined it as generic or not.

In your case, the code compiles as your `ArrayList` declaration is not generic, and it runs fine because of type erasure.

Answer (score 2):

`ArrayList value` this is your type declaration which is not generic. That is why compiler allows you to add any Object to the list.